# Custom Sorting of List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, sorting, lambda

I have a `List<T>` where `T` is my `Event` type which has a field `time` of type `long`. This list is populated from a web service and if an event doesn't have a time, the value set is 0.

What i want to do is sort my list ascending by time, but place the items with time=0 at the very bottom.

Currently I am accomplishing this in a hack sort of fashion and I want to learn a better way.

```
var events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(restResponse.Content).Items;

var notime = resp.Where(r => r.time == 0);
var yestime = resp.Where(r => r.time > 0);

yestime.ToList().ForEach(events.Add);
notime.ToList().ForEach(events.Add);

CallbackInternal(callback, events);
```

I attempted implementing a custom `IComparer`, but that didn't work out so well (here is one shot at it)

```
public class EventComparer : IComparer<Event>
{
    public int Compare(Event x, Event y)
    {
        if (x.time == 0) return 0;
        if (x.time < y.time) return -1;
        if (x.time > y.time) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

guidance is appreciated!

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
   events.OrderBy (e => e.Time == 0).ThenBy (e => e.Time);
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Bools can be sorted, too!

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ:

```
resp.OrderBy(i => i.time == 0 ? int.MaxValue : i.time);
```

Comment: I tried something along those lines, but just didn't get my logic right. It all seems so clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
 if(x.time==y.time) return 0;
 if(x.time==0) return 1;
 return x.time - y.time;
```

The point here is that 0 is larger than any other time, so it'll be placed at the end of the list.

Comment: thanks, I just couldn't seem to clearly think this one through. This helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your custom IComparer is incorrect.  With correct logic, it should work just fine.  The problem is that if the left value is zero, any value will be equal to it.  This means that `0 == 3` is true, and `3 > 0` is true.  In fact, `0 > 3` and `3 < 0` should be true

You should do something like this instead:

```
if (x.time == y.time) return 0;
if (x.time == 0) return 1;
if (y.time == 0) return -1;
return x.time.CompareTo(y.time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (you have to adjust it for your needs):

```
    class Comparer : IComparer<int>
    {
        public int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x == y) return 0;
            else if (x == 0) return 1;
            else if (y == 0) return -1;
            else if (x < y) return -1;
            else if (x > y) return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is broken for `.Compare(0, 0)`, which should return `0`, but returns `1`.

Comment: Compiler doesn't need these elses for sure; however I use to leave such redundant elses, if the comparisons are logically connected. It makes the code a little more readable in my opinion (especially if there are more instructions before the final return). Another aspect is the lack of last else (and return), however control would never reach that point, because all other options are exhausted earlier. Some compilers may complain, though.