# Sorting a List of Custom Objects

Tags: c#

I have a class called Person which contains a property LastName, which reflects a string cooresponding to the Person's last name.

I created a List as follows:

```
var People = List<Person>
```

What I would like to do is sort the people by their LastName property in alphabetical order.

After looking at some examples, I've tried

```
People = People.OrderBy(p => p.LastName);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: by the way, ALWAYS specify what you mean by `does not work`.  Is it a compilation error? or a runtime error?  or unexpected results?, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Custom Sorting of List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10049466/299327)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using LINQ, you'd need to convert the results back into a `List<Person>`:

```
People = People.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ToList();
```

Since `OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, you need the extra call `ToList()` to turn this back into a list.

However, since you effectively want an in-place sort, you can also use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) directly:

```
People.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.LastName.CompareTo(p2.LastName));
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is using `ToList():`

```
People = People.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ToList();
```

You need the `ToList` to create a new ordered  `List<Person>`

Another option to sort the original list is using [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
People.Sort((p1,p2) => p1.LastName.CompareTo(p2.LastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result of orderby to `.Tolist()` like below

```
var people = People.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ToList();
```